# How to use less jQuery in jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery

Here's a jsfiddle that works great. The HTML is good, but the problem is there's a LOT of jQuery. I'm sure there's a better way. Any help would be great!
https://jsfiddle.net/jrmleduc/q9dboshu/

```
<input type="radio" value="true" name="1" id="1"><br>
<span class="classname1"><label>One</label><br></span>

<input type="radio" value="true" name="2" id="2"><br>
<span class="classname2"><label>Two</label><br></span>

<input type="radio" value="true" name="3" id="3"><br>
<span class="classname3"><label>Three</label><br></span>

$("input[name='1']").attr("checked", false);
$("input[name='3']").attr("checked", false);
$("input[name='2']").attr("checked", false);
$("span.classname1").toggle(this.value === "false");
$("span.classname2").toggle(this.value === "false");
$("span.classname3").toggle(this.value === "false");

$("input[name='1']").on("click", function(){
    $("span.classname1").toggle(this.value === "true");
    $("span.classname2").toggle(this.value === "false");
    $("span.classname3").toggle(this.value === "false");
    $("input[name='2']").attr("checked", false);
    $("input[name='3']").attr("checked", false);
});

$("input[name='2']").on("click", function(){
    $("span.classname1").toggle(this.value === "false");
    $("span.classname2").toggle(this.value === "true");
    $("span.classname3").toggle(this.value === "false");
    $("input[name='1']").attr("checked", false);
    $("input[name='3']").attr("checked", false);
});

$("input[name='3']").on("click", function(){
    $("span.classname1").toggle(this.value === "false");
    $("span.classname2").toggle(this.value === "false");
    $("span.classname3").toggle(this.value === "true");
    $("input[name='1']").attr("checked", false);
    $("input[name='2']").attr("checked", false);
});
```

Comment: Remove all the javascript and give them the same name but different values. On change, show/hide based on value.

Comment: Also.... `checked` is a property, use the prop method to alter it. (after the above change, there will be no reason to alter it)

Comment: example: https://jsfiddle.net/p7hzdrom/

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this is exactly what I needed!! Fast and awesome!! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: My values are actually strings of text with spaced words, so this isn't working. (Sorry, my fault for an oversimplified HTML example). Am I probably botching up the syntax or is that a jQuery limitation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you add some more generic classes to your HTML, you can use those to select the entire group of elements more easily.

```
<input type="radio" value="true" name="1" id="1" class="accordion-radio"><br>
<span class="classname1 accordion-label"><label>One</label><br></span>

<input type="radio" value="true" name="2" id="2" class="accordion-radio"><br>
<span class="classname2 accordion-label"><label>Two</label><br></span>

<input type="radio" value="true" name="3" id="3" class="accordion-radio"><br>
<span class="classname3 accordion-label"><label>Three</label><br></span>
```

Then you can condense your code down and take advantage of jQuery's use of `$(this)` to select the item currently firing the event handler and use the fact to have unique `id` attributes on your elements.

```
$("input.accordion-radio").prop("checked", false);
$("span.accordion-label").toggle(this.value === "false");

$("input.accordion-radio").on("click", function(){
    $("span.accordion-label").toggle(this.value === "false");
    $("input.accordion-radio").not("#"+$(this).attr("id")).prop("checked", false);
    $("span.classname" + $(this).attr("id")).toggle(this.value === "true");
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/o8aehrk6/)

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion! I think i'll be using one of the simpler options above, but thanks for the additional option :)

Comment: @user3424554 Just make sure you accept the answer for the one you use do they can get the points. :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Funny story... I can't use any of these actually... 2 of them depend on the ID value which I can't actually use on my website, and I'm still trying to get the css one to work, as I can't figure out how to select the sibling span of a radio that's inside a label, depending on the radio's checked status. If you can help with that that would be great! Anyway, my fault for using oversimplified HTML in the example... Lol. I think I'll end up needing to use the same amt of jQuery as in my question.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little fragile, but this is a quick way to do it.

```
const allInputs = $('input');

// Loop through all inputs, 
// if checked, show the span, else hide the span
const showOnlyChecked = function(){
    allInputs.each(function(index, item){
    if (item.checked === false){
        $(item).next().next().hide(); // next() > <br> > next() > <span?
    } else {
        $(item).next().next().show();
    }
    })
}

showOnlyChecked(); 
$('body').on('click', 'input', showOnlyChecked);
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8L1s3au/2/)**

You should know that if you give all the radio boxes the same `name=""` attribute, then by default the browser will only let you select one of the group. That's just how Radio Buttons work...

[Learn About Radio Buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Not sure I'll be using this, but always great to have another option :)

Answer (score -1):

CSS only solution:

```css
input[name="radio"]+br+span {
  display: none;
}

input[name="radio"]:checked+br+span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="1"><br>
<span class="classname"><label for="1">One</label><br></span>

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="2"><br>
<span class="classname"><label for="2">Two</label><br></span>

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="3"><br>
<span class="classname"><label for="3">Three</label><br></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looking for jQuery for now, but I'm sure this will help someone else! Hey I may even end up going this way at some point :)

Comment: @user3424554 aww this was as little jQuery as you could get ! : P

Comment: hahah actually yeah, good point - technically speaking you did win this question ;D